# struct definition inside main() causing Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, struct, solaris, sunstudio, cc

Is it not possible to define structure inside main() .
I tried the following only to get a Segmentation Fault:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <strings.h>
#define TRUE 1


void main(int argc,char **argv)
{
struct test_struct
{

        char test_name[50];
        char summary_desc[200];
        char result[50];
};

struct suite_struct
{
        char suite_name[50];
        struct test_struct test[500];
        int test_count;
        int passed;
        int failed;
        int unresolved;
        int notrun;
}suite[500];

        int a,b;

        for (a=0;a<500;a++)
        {
                strcpy(suite[a].suite_name,"");
                for (b=0;b<500;b++)
                {
                        strcpy(suite[a].test[b].test_name,"");
                        strcpy(suite[a].test[b].summary_desc,"");
                        strcpy(suite[a].test[b].result,"");
                }
                suite[a].test_count=0;
                suite[a].passed=0;
                suite[a].failed=0;
                suite[a].unresolved=0;
                suite[a].notrun=0;
        }
}
```

But the moment I take the struct definition outside it works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <strings.h>
#define TRUE 1


struct test_struct 
{ 

        char test_name[50]; 
        char summary_desc[200]; 
        char result[50]; 
}; 

struct suite_struct 
{ 
        char suite_name[50]; 
        struct test_struct test[500]; 
        int test_count; 
        int passed; 
        int failed; 
        int unresolved; 
        int notrun; 
}suite[500]; 
void main(int argc,char **argv)
{

        int a,b;

        for (a=0;a<500;a++)
        {
                strcpy(suite[a].suite_name,"");
                for (b=0;b<500;b++)
                {
                        strcpy(suite[a].test[b].test_name,"");
                        strcpy(suite[a].test[b].summary_desc,"");
                        strcpy(suite[a].test[b].result,"");
                }
                suite[a].test_count=0;
                suite[a].passed=0;
                suite[a].failed=0;
                suite[a].unresolved=0;
                suite[a].notrun=0;
        }
}
```

Not sure why this is happening. 
I am using the Solaris SunStudio compiler for this.

Comment: `void main` **RAAAAAARRRRRRGGGGGGHHHHHH!**

Comment: You really should **learn to use a debugger**. Did you try to compile your program with warnings and debugging information enabled (with `gcc` that means `-Wall -g`)? Did you use the debugger? We could find your bug, but you really should learn to debug by yourself....

Comment: void main is illegal. The structs seem Ok. But they are rather big for automatic storage.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch: The compiler I have used is cc. And the debugger in Solaris is mdb .. the stack trace shows the following: mdb core
Loading modules: [ libc.so.1 ld.so.1 ]
> ::stack
main+9(1, 804790c, 8047914, feffb934)
_start+0x7d(1, 80479ec, 0, 80479f1, 80479fe, 8047a12)   Not sure what exactly to look for from this ? There are not many tutorials to use mdb for user programs .

Comment: You still need to learn how to use your compiler (including getting all the warnings it can give you) and how to use your debugger (including understanding its messages). The C language is unsafe, and even experimented programmers need to take care of compiler warnings and to use the debugger.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch: Thank you for your advice ... Will definitely kepp that in mind the next time .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first example, `suite` lives on the stack, and in the second it lives on the data segment.

Since `suite` is quite large (~75MB), the segfault is almost certainly due to your program running out of stack space.

In most cases, it is best to allocate large data structures on the heap (using `malloc()` et al). This will also make it possible to allocate just the amount of space you require instead of always allocating space for 500 elements.

Comment: is there a way to increase stack space ?

Comment: @tomkaith13 that's the wrong question to be asking. Define the structs outside of `main()` or in a header file, and allocate space on the heap for them with `malloc()`.

Comment: @aix: I was about to post the same thing, then misread your username as mine and had a complete WTF moment.

Comment: @aix: its just some rough code ( the number 500)  I wanted to write.. and I was lazy to create a linked list...Lesson Learnt !! :) Thanks

Comment: @aix: Sorry for bothering you but I need to ask you more details regarding the crash . I checked the solaris stack size using ulimit -Ss which is arnd 10MB. I know from the address space layour that the stack starts from 0x8048000 and grows downwards. so the stack should end at 0x76BE980.. but since suite is 75mb the new %esp value is 0x038b8364.. this is the problem ?? am i right ??

Answer (score 3):

It is okay to declare a structure inside main. But in your program, the problem has got to do with the fact that you are creating 500 objects of that structure inside main function. Each object is about 15 KB in size. So, 500 objects require about 75 MB. Try `printf("size: %lu\n", sizeof suite);`.

You don't have that much of stack available by default. You can find the available stack using the command `ulimit -s`. It prints the available stack in KBs.

You can use the `ulimit` command to increase the stack. e.g. `ulimit -s 100000`.

A better approach is to dynamically allocate the memory you require using `malloc()`.

Answer (score 1):

It is legal to define a `struct` and to declare a local variable of that `struct` inside any function, including `main`.

But a code can be syntactically legal and crash at runtime (e.g. because it has an undefined behavior, per the C standard, or because it hits some system limitation, like a limit on the call stack).

Answer (score 1):

The struct you define outside of main is global and uninitialized so it will go into the .bss segment and be initialized to 0 at the start of execution. The struct you define inside main is huge and exceeds the maximum stack size (which is about 1-2MB on Linux and probably Solaris too). Since the one outside of main is not on the stack, it appears to work in that case and not the other.

Comment: Default stack size on SuSE is 8192K. Still far short of the needed ~75M though.

Comment: Actually it looks like I was thinking of Windows for 1-2MB

Answer (score 1):

In addition to answers about stack space, malloc, and undefined behavior . . .

When I tried to compile your code, I got 3 warnings.

```
test.c:7:6: warning: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:32:17: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strcpy’
test.c:32:17: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strcpy’
```

Return an int for main, not void.

```
int main(int argc,char **argv)
```

In C, the header for strcpy is string.h, not strings.h.